# .htaccess to nginx.conf Rewrite rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx

I'm switching from .htaccess to nginx.conf and I have trouble translating this lines for nginx:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|uploads|fav.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I tried this:

```
if ($1 !~ "^(index\.php|assets|uploads|fav.ico)"){
       set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
}
if ($rule_0 = "1"){
       rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
}
```

and this:

```
location /$ {
    index       index.php;
    # Removes index.php from URLs
    rewrite_log on;
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
      rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
    }
}
```

but none work :(. What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try translating this piece of code.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(index\.php|assets|uploads|fav.ico) - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

The problem you have is because apache first executes the RewriteRule, before the RewriteCond. Your nginx code is run sequentially, so $1 is not yet set when you read it out.

I don't know nginx, but I think this might be what you would get, if you translate the above:

```
rewrite ^/(index\.php|assets|uploads|fav.ico) - last
rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
```

or else

```
rewrite ^/(index\.php|assets|uploads|fav.ico).*$ $0 last
rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
```